# How to always display 1st item of collection view, if collection view is embedded in table view in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have one table view and in custom cell of table view I have one collection view.
Collection view has horizontal scrolling with multiple images.
On first cell of table view I have scrolled 3 to 4 images from collection view, means I am on 1st row of table view and on 4th image of collection view with horizontal scrolling. 
Now when I go to or scroll down table view to 5th row, collection view directly take me to image at index which I scrolled in collection view previously. I should be at 1st index of collection view every time I scroll table view.

Comment: In tableViewCell, override: `prepareForReuse()`and reload the `collectionView` or scroll it to position 0.

Answer (score 1):

use this in willDisplayCell method of table view.

let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

tableViewCell.collectionView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

Use [prepareForReuse()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) method in custom `TableView` cell and reset `UICollectionView` scroll.

Note: this approach will work but scroll inset is always resetted. So, in your example, if you scroll down and then return to first cell, then it won't showing 4th image but will show the first. If you want to achieve a better solution, create an array of double to remember internal `UICollectionViews` cells contentInsets and then use these values in prepareForReuse method to set right scroll on `UICollectionView`. This approach could be expensive for memory usage.